# Show only related entity in ASP.NET MVC using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am pretty new to MVC and I am working on a personal project using it in combination with EntityFramework. I am starting from an existing database where I have a class  `Customer` with some related entities, one of them is the `Address` one.

So, for example :

```
public partial class Customer
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Customer
        {            
            this.Address = new HashSet<Address>();
        }
    
        public System.Guid CustomerId { get; set; }   
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }        
        public string CustomerCountry { get; set; }
        
        public virtual ICollection<Address> Address { get; set; }
```

Then I have :

```
 public partial class Address
    {
        public System.Guid AddressId { get; set; }
        public System.Guid CustomerFk { get; set; }
        public string City{ get; set; }
        public string Street{ get; set; }
        public string PostalCode{ get; set; }            
        public System.DateTime ValidFromDt { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime ValidToDt { get; set; }            
    
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So, in this scenario a customer can have multiple addresses and the actual one is considered the valid one based on the `ValidFromDt` and `ValidToDt` fields.
I want to show in a view a table with some of the customers and their addresses but I'm struggling because I don't know which is the correct way to show in the same view the data of the customer and the data of the valid only address. My focus is to show/work on the single instance of the related entity.

In my first approach I've used a `ViewModel` :

```
public class CustomerListViewModel
    {       

        public Guid CustomerID { get; set; }        

        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        
        [Display(Name = "Country")]
        public string CustomerCountry { get; set; }       


        [Display(Name = "City")]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Street")]
        public string Street { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Postal code")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    }
}
```

But I've noted that back in the `CustomerController` I have to query a list of customers, then for each of them I have to extract the single address based on the validity condition, and then I have to map this fields to the `ViewModel`, and this process seems very inefficient (also considering that maybe I should do this for another action when I edit the data of a customer).

Is there a more efficient way to proceed?
Is it correct for example to query the single address directly in the `View` using the Razor sintax?
Should I use a `ViewModel` built on the combination of multiple `ViewModels`?

Probably I am still missing something EF side.

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: seperate views.you want to show customer on main page and then show address on click on another page so this is the correct way m in mvc means model yes you can create view model but actually in my opinion that is wrong ok so first create a controller that gets customer id and show its address then show the addresses in view

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path. A view model represents what your view needs. Entities reflect your domain, so the bridge is projecting your domain into what the view needs.

Given your example, when returning a customer you want their applicable address for a given date. For instance, defaulting to the current date. I'm assuming since the ValidTo date is not null-able, the current address would have a ValidTo date set to something like DateTime.Max()?

Something like this should point you in the right direction:

```
public CustomerViewModel GetCustomerAsAt(Guid customerId, DateTime? targetDate = null)
{
    if (!targetDate.HasValue)
        targetDate = DateTime.Today;

    var customer = _context.Customers
        .Where(c => c.CustomerId == customerId)
        .Select(c => new {
        {
            c.CustomerId,
            c.CustomerName,
            Address = c.Address
                .SingleOrDefault(a => a.ValidFromDt <= targetDate && a.ValidToDt > targetDate);
        }).Single();
    var viewModel = new CustomerViewModel
    {
        CustomerId = customer.CustomerId,
        CustomerName = customer.CustomerName,
        Country = customer.Address?.Country,
        City = customer.Address?.City,
        Street = customer.Address?.Street,
        Postcode = customer.Address?.Postcode,
    };

    return viewModel;
}
```

The Linq-to-EF expression can be adjusted to project to the view model directly, though I opted for a 2-step approach to make it more readable. The method accepts an optional date to find the address that applied at that date, defaulting to today's date if none was provided. The method will throw an exception if the Customer ID is not valid, but will return empty address details if the customer had no address details spanning the desired date. It will throw if multiple addresses span the date.

"this process seems very inefficient"

It is a cost of separating concerns between data/domain, and what a view needs. While it may seem like more code, it gives you full control over the size of the payload being shuttled between server and client. In most cases where the projection is kept quite simple, you can leverage Automapper and it's `ProjectTo` method to manage the mapping. Then it's literally just a one-statement in the fluent chain with a `.ProjectTo<CustomerViewModel>(mapperConfig)`. It's likely possible to wire up your example /w Automapper, though I tend to use ProjectTo to very simple (though maybe larger entities) such as when mapping a detailed view of an entity as a view model graph.

For messages back to the server, I favor using a more DDD approach using mutator methods for altering entities rather than public Setters. So my controller methods by extension may pass ViewModels with the applicable data, or they will simply pass the parameter values that I wish to update, if there isn't enough to justify a view model. I rarely ever pass a view model that was provided to a view back to the server, even though that's how technologies like MVC were set up by default. My view is often comprised of several smaller partial viewmodels pulled on demand, with one or more actions to send in return.

Actions are geared towards passing only the data needed to perform an update. I'd never accept something like a "UpdateCustomer" passing in a assuredly whole CustomerViewModel/Entity with it's address history structure to copy over my customer data row. If there is an action to update a customer address, I would expect to have a method called `UpdateCustomerAddress(customerAddressViewModel)` passing only the fields that can be updated, with my business logic validating that and calling `customer.UpdateAddress()` to handle ensuring the historical nature of my address history is managed properly.  It may be more verbose in the code, but it is simple in purpose, and it reduces side-effects and exploitation.

Comment: Hello Steve, thanks for your answer. I have another question, is it correct to have a method that returns a ViewModel? Shouldn't they only be used to show data in a view? Furthermore where should I put this method? Directly in the controller? I still have some doubts about where to put what. Thanks

Comment: I generally have view models returned by the controller methods or a common service class if multiple controllers might use them, such as for DTOs return via an API etc. The patterns I commonly favour is a unit of work (DbContextScope) that allows the controller (or service) actions to control the lifetime scope of the access to the domain, and a simple Repository pattern that returns `IQueryable<Entity>`. Entities are not returned beyond the scope of the unit of work, the controller/service projects these to the view models to be returned.

Comment: Repositories accommodate core business filters, while the controllers/services are free to tweak business rules specific to their needs by appending conditions to the `IQueryable` along with paging, sorting, and projection.